# Facebook login fails on deployed Meteor application

Tags: facebook, meteor, nginx, facebook-oauth, meteor-accounts

I'm using the extended accounts package 'accounts-facebook'. When I run my application locally, the login authentication procedure works after adding 'http://localhost:3000/_oauth/facebook?close' under Valid OAuth redirect URIs.

After deploying the application however, the login pop-up gives no error, but remains blank without completing the authentication procedure. I've tried adding 'http://www.algoloom.com/_oauth/facebook?close' and loads of possible variations to this, as some other forum discussions suggest, but the login procedure is never completed.

While I was testing my application in its deployed version, I managed to get Facebook login working by changing its ROOT_URL to 'http://www.algoloom.com:3010', in combination with 'http://www.algoloom.com:3010/_oauth/facebook?close' as a redirect URI. Now that I've set nginx to redirect to port 3010 by default, the 3010 disappears from the main website URL. As a result I've also set my ROOT_URL to 'http://www.algoloom.com'. This works fine for any other website functionality, but I can't seem to fix my my issues with Facebook login.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: what happens when you try to login ? have you tried to send a CURL request to your callback URL ? is it timing out ?

Comment: When I try to login a window pops up with the link http://www.algoloom.com/_oauth/facebook?close&code=AQ....0%3D#_=_. This window stays white and the console prints out: "This redirect failed because the redirect URI is not whitelisted in the app’s Client OAuth Settings. Make sure Client and Web OAuth Login are on and add all your app domains as Valid OAuth Redirect URIs". When I copy this link from the popup window and paste it in a new tab, it says something like "login success", but this doesn't have any impact on my login attempt. I haven't tried a CURL request, how does that work exactly?